Largest RKHS norm of 1-Lipschitz functions on bounded domain and range
The objective is to find the largest RKHS norm of 1-Lipschitz functions on bounded domain and range:
$$\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \langle f, f \rangle_\mathcal{H}$$
The domain is the p-dimensional hypercube $\Theta=[0,l]^p$ and the range is $[0, 1]$.
We consider the subset of the RKHS where functions are 1-Lipschitz and on this bounded domain and range:
$$\mathcal{F} = \{f :  [0,l]^p \rightarrow [0, 1] \  \ | \  \ \max_x |\nabla_x f(x)| \leq 1 \}$$
We may assume that the RKHS corresponds to the Gaussian kernel, $k(x,y) = e^{\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2} |x-y|^2}$ with $k(\cdot, \cdot): \Theta \times \Theta \rightarrow \mathrm{R}_{+}$.
Related sources:
Related work exists on RKHS and Lipschitz, but that only concerns Lipschitzness of the full RKHS. This question explicitly concerns a subset of functions that is 1-Lipschitz. Another related question shows a counter-example, but we have the additional assumption that the range is bounded.
The approach I have tried is writing the kernel expansion $f(x) = \int_\Theta b(y) k(x,y) dy$. Then the norm follows from the reproducing property $\langle f, f \rangle_\mathcal{H} = \int_\Theta \int_\Theta b(x) b(y) k(x, y) dx dy$. However, that hasn't yielded an upper bound yet. Unless one could upperbound $\int_\Theta |b(y)|dy$ or $\int_\Theta (b(y))^2 dy$.
Any comments would be appreciated.

Can you solve this for with $\mathcal{F}$:  $\langle \nabla_x f(x),  \nabla_x f(x) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \leq 1$? I guess this is more or less standard. Then you can try ask something nice from kernel to link this and in $L_2$.
